# Xamarin Studio Community version 6.1.3 does not show iOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have downloaded the latest Xamarin Studio for Mac. Surprisingly it's not showing up the iOS Project. 
What I am missing?

[image: Xamarin Studio Community edition]

Comment: What version of macOS and Xcode do you have install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Ensure Xamarin.iOS Installed

Download the [Xamarin Universal Installer](https://www.xamarin.com/download), and run it again. The universal installer will automatically detect if you don't have Xamarin.iOS installed and it will automatically install it for you.

## 2. Ensure Xcode is Updated, Installed & Configured

#### a. Download/Update Xcode

Open the App Store app on macOS and search for Xcode. From this screen, download/update and install Xcode.

[image]

#### b. Run Xcode Once

In order for Xamarin Studio to connect to Xcode, you have to open and run Xcode at least once after installing/updating Xcode.

Open and run Xcode, accept all of the prompts, and wait for Xcode to finish initializing.

## 3. Ensure Xamarin Studio Is Pointed to Xcode

Open Xamarin Studio Preferences and ensure that Xamarin Studio is pointed to the correct version of Xcode on your machine

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brandon. I did download the universal one. No luck. Trying again.